# Await a synchronous method which has an asynchronous method invoked in it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin

There is a library which has a normal method invoking an async method. So how do I await the async call from the application where the library is being used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a library which has a normal method invoking an async method. So how do I await the async call from the application where the library is being used.

You can't.

The library is already doing sync-over-async, and only exposes a synchronous API. Thus, the only option you have is to call it synchronously.

If you want an asynchronous API, you'll need to contact the library authors.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = await YourLibrary.AMethodOfYourLibraryAsync(...);
```

please note that also the method containing your awaited call should be marked as async

Answer (score -1):

You can call `.Result` or `.Wait()` on the `task` returned depending on the nature of the call.